# Does caffeine from cold brew coffee get absorbed slower than normal coffee?

Tags: caffeine

A person who was selling cold brew coffee claimed that it the body absorbed the caffeine from cold brew coffee slower than it does from hot pressed coffee such as an espresso.

Is there any scientific basis to this?

**The claim**

> CAFFEINE WITHOUT THE CRASH
>
> While regular coffee can often leave you feeling jittery and prone to
>   an energy crash, First Press Coffee’s caffeine hit is a completely
>   different experience to what you might be used to. First Press Coffee
>   gives you the best of both worlds, the benefits of caffeine on your
>   mental alertness and physical performance without the shakes and
>   crashes most typically get from hot coffee due to our cold extraction
>   process.

Provided here: http://firstpresscoffee.com/pages/cold-drip-coffee

Wikipedia cold brew: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_brew

Comment: The wikipage you linked sais: By brewing the coffee at lower temperatures, many of these solubles do not completely dissolve, resulting in lower acidity and lower caffeine content when brewed in equal volume. So it might just be an effect because of the lower caffeine content.

Comment: Thats not exactly the same claim, e.g. less caffeine vs caffeine that processes more slowly and hence no crash.

Comment: I know, what I ment is that it is probably a fancy way of saying our coffees contain less caffeine. But the claim you posted from the site doesn't actually say anything about it being absorbed slower. Just less jitter and crash.

Comment: But if its just from less caffeine then you would not get the same alertness as the higher caffeine (i know this is a tad simplistic).  Also the in person discussion (Not on this website) alluded to something being diffent.